# Fedora 38: Davinci resolve no longer opens after updating from fedora 37 to 38

Tags: fedora

I'm fairly new to linux and was running fedora 37. When the new release for fedora 38 came out i decided to upgrade. After doing so davinci resolve stopped working. It doesnt even launch, I just get a spinning ball like it's loading and then it quietly fails.

When trying to trying to launch it from opt/resolve/bin/resolve using the terminal I get the following: ./resolve: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_string_free_and_steal which after googling I was still unsure about.

I have attempted to completely uninstall it and reinstall with the same issue. If someone could explain either what how to fix symbol lookup error or simply what went wrong I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Running resolve from terminal with the following preload allows it to run without modifying it's install:

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so"
```

Answer (score 2):

Davinci Resolve uses its own libraries instead of using system ones but not all of them. It loads libpango from the system, which in turn loads glib2 from the resolve libs directory (/opt/resolve/libs), even though it needs the system glib2 or the newer version.

You could just copy the system library to resolve libs folder and it will start working again:

```
sudo cp /lib64/libglib-2.0.* /opt/resolve/libs/
```

Thanks to this Reddit [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/12rhba8/comment/jgvgk6y/?context=3) which helped me understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the libs as mentioned by @talk2arpan works.
But removing the resolve libs is cleaner imho, so updates work.
When resolve's own libs are removed, it used the system ones automatically

`sudo rm /opt/resolve/libs/libglib-2.0.so*`

First start throws blank screen. Second and later work fine.